# Is it possible to name events differently from "message" in the NodeJS cluster module?

Tags: node.js, multiprocessing, node-cluster

I'm wondering (since there's no mention of this in the official documentation) if there's a way to emit events from the `worker` processes which have a different event name from the default, which is *message*, so that I can set up listeners in the master process something along the lines of:

`worker.once('someOtherMsgName', fn)`

This is so that I can avoid conditions in the actual callback function and only match the listeners to execute the callback for appropriate messages by their message name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

"message" means - you have got new incoming message received by IPC (inter process communication). NodeJS has only one build-in way to send messages between process - [process.send](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) and [child_process.send](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback)

**Yes**

Of course you can use third party modules ([node-ipc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-ipc) for example) or make node to interpret message contents in any way you want:

main.js

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process');
const fork = childProcess.fork(__dirname + '/fork.js');
const initIPC = require('./init-ipc');

initIPC(process);
fork.on('hello', event => {
  console.log(event.hello);
});

// Say hello to forked process
fork.send({event: 'hello', hello: 'Hello from main process!'});
```

fork.js

```js
const initIPC = require('./init-ipc');

initIPC(process);
process.on('hello', event => {
  console.log(event.hello);
});

// Say hello to main process
process.send({event: 'hello', hello: 'Hello from forked process!'});
```

init-ipc.js

```js
exports.initIPC = function (process) {
    process.on('message', message => {
        if (('event' in message) && typeof message.event === 'string') {
            process.emit(message.event, message);
        }
    });
};
```